# Is there Bloom Filter UDF function in Hive?

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, bloom-filter

Having troubles with big full fact table joins incremental fact table, I know Bloom Filter is good choice to reduce No. of rows to join, but there is few Bloom UDF implementation, only I can find is the brickhouse's Bloom UDF, and is not very sufficient to use, you need to read small table and load bloom data to local directory first to use it later.
So, is there any better implementation of Bloom Filter UDF that I can directly use in Hive(just upload the JAR)? Thanks.

Comment: ORC has embedded bloom filter

Comment: @leftjoin yeah thx for mentioning, but I am not sure if orc's bloom is gonna work in join if we just set the "orc.bloom.filter.columns"="xx" for the table. Have u try it, is it work?

Comment: I have tried and noticed improvement only if ORC was loaded sorted.

Answer (score 0):

during these days I have found 2 repositories which have Bloomfilter UDF functions, one is Hivemall, which is meanly used for machine learning, the other is Brickhouse. However, both of them can't solve my problem. For the Brickhouse's Bloomfilter UDAF, it requires you to store temporary bloom result in local directory to be used later, but when this bloom result is big enough, it can fullfill the memory of local server and caused the hiveserver in this machine shutdown. The Hivemall's one, it works for small dataset, but when the dataset become big, like million's of unique id's, it throws exception, still can't figure out why, but looks like it can't handle long string id's (length from 40 to 50) and cannot deal with millions of id's in its data structure. It's weird because both UDF data structure is byte array, supposed to supports unlimited number of id's.

Comment: Hey guys I just found the problem with second bloom udf, the Hivemall one, the error is due to the "expected number of elements" parameters is too small when new a Bloomfilter instance, now the UDF works, I am so glad. Hope this helps.